# Getting object properties via ngModel select list in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm have a problem fetching the properties of an object which has been selected from a select list in Angular 2 (RC1). Take the following syntax:

```
<select required [(ngModel)]="model.plan">
  <option selected="selected" disabled>Plan...</option>
  <option *ngFor="#plan of plans" [value]="plan">{{ plan.name }}</option>
</select>
```

Where `plans` is defined as an array of objects:

```
[{ name: 'Plan 1' }, { name: 'Plan 2' }]
```

If you try and output the value of one of the keys of the selected object, nothing appears to be displayed:

```
<p>{{ model.plan?.name }}</p> // Shows nothing if a plan is selected
```

[Here is a fork of the Angular2 form live demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VIJgaoUh0NpIjTCDUkLq?p=preview), showing this problem. Select "Plan 2" from the select list, and see that nothing is displayed.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To use objects as value use `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`. `[value]` only supports string ids.

```
<select required [(ngModel)]="model"> <!-- <== changed -->
  <option selected="selected" disabled>Plan...</option>
  <option *ngFor="#plan of plans" [ngValue]="plan">{{ plan.name }}</option>
</select>
```

[**Plunker example**](http://plnkr.co/edit/v3CsDeWmISrL2LvEvbTD?p=preview)

`model` needs to point to one of the elements in `plans` to work as default value (it needs to be the same instance, not another instance containing the same values).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, there's still an issue with two-way binding to a `select`. So try this:

**Template**

```
<select required [(ngModel)]="model.plan" (change)="setPlan($event.target.value)">
    <option selected="selected" disabled>Plan...</option>
    <option *ngFor="#plan of plans" [value]="plan.name">{{ plan.name }}</option>
</select>
```

**Component Class**

```
setPlan(value) {
    //if you're on older versions of ES, use for-in instead
    var plan = this.plans.find(p => p.name = value);

    if(plan) { this.model.plan = plan; }
}
```

Couldn't try it, for some reason plunkr has never worked for me.