# Angular: How do I dynamically select first item of select component

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display the first select item of a select box by targeting the index, selected="index==0", as shown below but this is no succeeding. How do I accomplish this?

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-4">
    <select class="pull-right border-outset3 p-a-pt5 w-15" [(ngModel)]="sortValue"
      (change)="sortProducts()">
      <optgroup label="Sort By:">
        <option *ngFor="let menu of sortMenu$ | async; let ndx=index"
          value="{{menu.value}}" selected="ndx==0">
          {{menu.label}}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: `[(ngModel)]="sortValue"` set sortValue to sortMenu$[0]

Comment: Not clear on what you mean.

Comment: Your model for the select is `sortValue`. Whatever that value is that matches an option is displayed.

Comment: Should I set sortValue to sortMenu$[0] within the component? Because sortValue is not a property of select so it won't let me. Could you show this in code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37670210/7733570

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a modified version of the Observable (e.g. `sortMenuDefault`), in which the value of the first item is assigned to `sortValue` with the `do` operator:

```
this.sortMenuDefault = this.sortMenu$.do(items => {
  if (!this.sortValue && items && items.length > 0) {
    this.sortValue = items[0].value;
  }
});
```

and use that Observable in the template:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="sortValue" ...>
  <option *ngFor="let menu of sortMenuDefault | async" [value]="menu.value">
    {{menu.label}}
  </option>
</select>
```

See [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7u6svm) for a demo.