# Is there a way to save the data from dropdownlist-input field?

Tags: html, angular

So I have this HTML field where I can Input some text. I can send it to API and it has no problem with it. However is it possible to have the input field as a dropdown list and get the same outcome?

I have tried one way, but I cant still bind  2 properties into my `NgModel` to get the data going into my API. So I had these hardcoded lists in my .ts file to test if this method works. I get the value into my input field, but I cannot send it to API.

HTML

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center start">
  <div fxLayout="column" class="term-detail">
     <ejs-dropdownlist [dataSource]='data' [(value)]='value' placeholder='Select a Term'></ejs-dropdownlist>
     <div style='margin-top: 50px'>
        <input matInput type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" />
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
  <button (click)="onSave()">Tallenna</button>
```

TYPESCRIPT  FILE

```
export class SelectTermComponent implements OnInit {

  terms: Term;

  constructor(private service: TermService, private httpService: TermHttpService, private router: Router ) {

    this.terms = new Term();
   }

    public data: string[] = ['Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3', 'Test 4'];

    public value: 'Badminton';


  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onSave() {
    console.log('data sent to DB!');
    this.httpService.create(this.terms).subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result);
    });

    this.router.navigate(['termselected']);
    console.log('navigated to termSelected');

  }
```

This is how it works without the dropdownlist select:

```
<mat-form-field floatPlaceholder="auto">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="terms.source" required
             placeholder="Lähtökäsite">
</mat-form-field>
```

Term.ts

```
export class Term {
  termId: number;
  termValue: string;
  termArrow: string;
  source: number;
  target: number;

  constructor(termId?: number, termValue?: string, termArrow?: string, source?: number, target?: number) {

    this.termId = termId;
    this.termValue = termValue;
    this.termArrow = termArrow;
    this.source = source;
    this.target = target;

  }

}
```

I expect the data to go into the API but since `ngModel` has the 'value' binding instead of 'term.x' I think it is not the way it should be. Any ideas?

Comment: did try binding your mode to the dropdown list? ... `(onChange)` should also work. and why are you binding value ?? any reasons for that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37669365/getting-object-properties-via-ngmodel-select-list-in-angular-2

Comment: @kcsujeet The dropdownlist-input is not working if it does not include the 'value'. I was trying to figure out how it works